# MQTT Last will is not retaining

Tags: c, arduino, rabbitmq, mqtt, arduino-esp8266

I bought a Huzzah ESP8266 which I'm using to control an LED strip through a web client.

I implemented a rabbitmq mqtt server on a raspberry pi.

I started out using the PubSubClient library for mqtt. Everything was going pretty smoothly until I tried sending a Last will message that would be retained.

```
byte willQoS = 0;
const char* willTopic = "tv/pixel/status";
const char* willMessage = "turn off";
boolean willRetain = true;

client.connect("Pixel", "username", "password", willTopic, willQoS, willRetain, willMessage);
```

Which results in the payload being sent on timeout but it does not retain.
I'm at a loss I've tried changing the variable around, looked through the .cpp library but I don't know enough about mqtt and C++ to solve it

If this is a bug is there any other mqtt libraries out for arduino/esp8266 that I can send last will messages that can be retained?

Answer (score 0):

I have used mosquitto and it works perfectly fine. 
It also provides pubsub library in setup.

This is the will messages for

> In MQTT, you use the Last Will and Testament (LWT) feature to notify other clients about an ungracefully disconnected client. Each client can specify its last will message when it connects to a broker.

I hope u expects the same thing.